# project and workspace on same pane when switching change project in sublime text3

Tags: sublime-text

Whenever I switch my project in sublime text 3 from **Tools > Switch project** and the Switch project modal list all the workspaces and project together and sometimes there are more than 1 workspaces within same directory.So it became confusing and mixed up.

So my query is How can we distinguish/separate/hideout the `.sublime-project` and `.sublime-workspace` files.

[image: workspace and project file]

Answer (score 0):

I find the way to rid out this on **ubuntu 14.04**

1. Close sublime text 3
2. go **home > .config > sublime-text-3 > Local** folder
3. open *Session.sublime_session* file in gedit ( i.e. other than sublime text )
4. search `recent workspaces` block (find at the bottom of the file ) and remove the un necessary  workspaces from this list

   ```
    "workspaces":
   {
       "recent_workspaces":
       [...here listed all workspaces..]
   }
   ```